# Sphinx JSONHTMLBuilder: what's fjson?

Tags: json, python-sphinx

The [Sphinx JSON builder `JSONHTMLBuilder`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinxcontrib.serializinghtml.JSONHTMLBuilder) creates JSON files instead of the traditional HTML files. However, some of the files are `.fjson`. What's the difference with a regular `.json`?

Comment: See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5599 (issue closed in March 2019). Btw, there is a Python module called `fjson` (https://github.com/nschloe/fjson), but I don't know if it has anything to do with that Sphinx issue.

Comment: maybe fjson means "json with nested format". Like in that case "json with float formatting". Maybe fjson for sphinx means "json with html"?